# Laravel 5 Blade Mystery

Tags: laravel

I am having a curious blade problem.

I have an edit blade that is rendering, but not with the master blade.  Debugbar shows that both views (master and delete) are being shown.  They are not!

Other blades used in conjunction with master all work.  I tried duplicating those blades and inserting the specific data to no avail.

I have cleared history in the browser and done php artisan cache:clear.  Nothing.

Master Blade is working for all other renderings.  Here is detail:

```
      <div class="intro">
        <section>
        @yield('intro')
    </section>
  </div>
```

This blade works and is rendered with the master:

```
@extends('layouts.master')


   @section('title')
Your Profile
@stop


@section('head')
@stop


@section('intro')
<div class="output">
<h2>Your Pets</h2>
<div>

</div>
@if(sizeof($pets) == 0)
  No pets
@else
  @foreach($pets as $pet)
  <div class="p1">
    <h3>{{ $pet->petName }}</h3>
        <p><img src='{{ $pet->photo }}' width="200px" height="200px"></p>
      <p>{{ $pet->breed }}</p>
      <a href='/profile/edit/{{$pet->id}}'>Edit</a> |
          <a href='/profile/confirm-delete/{{$pet->id}}'>Delete</a>

  </div>
 @endforeach
 @endif
 </div>

@stop

@section('body')

@stop
```

This blade renders but with no master!  Debugbar says that both views are rendering.  Ha!

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title')
Delete Your Pet
@stop

@section('head')
@stop

@section('intro')
<div class="output">
<h1>Delete Pet</h1>

<p>
    Are you sure you want to delete <em>{{$pets->petName}}</em>?
</p>

<p>
    <a href='/profile/delete/{{$pets->id}}'>Yes...</a>
</p>
 </div>
@stop
@section('body')

@stop
```

Anyone seen this?

Comment: Use `@endSection` instead of `@stop`, may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

`@stop` was removed from the docs as of 5.1, so I would guess it is probably no longer supported. Use `@endsection` instead.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade